# Cardslib padding - native_list_card_layout

Tags: android, cardslib, android-cards

im not sure why the cards inside the grid i have always have that 1dp of padding. I cant find which attributes to remove it.

This is the grid code that i am using:

```
    <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardGridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="190dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    card:list_card_layout_resourceID="@layout/native_list_card_layout"
    android:id="@+id/myGrid" />
```

How could i remove that 1dp padding from "native_list_card_layout" ???

[image]

Comment: Where is native_list_card_layout?

Comment: @Harry it belongs to the Cardslib

Comment: You may have to go through all styles in library, instead assign -1 padding to your layout

Comment: there's a special TopColored card that you can use if you want to give a topcolor https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/TOPCOLORED.md